# Excel VBA user form

Tags: excel, vba

I created a userform that I would like to keep open on my desk top. Problem is I cannot open an existing excel spread sheet. I have to close my userform first or open the program excel and then open my worksheet. I cannot go to "my documents" and open an existing excel worksheet directly. Any idea's would be greatly appreciated. I am not the only person using the VBA userform.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the Userform's `ShowModal` property to `False`